# Laravel + Shopify Osiset productVariantUpdate GraphQL

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, shopify

I want update the prices of product variants in bulk using "osiset/Basic-Shopify-API" package.

This query works perfectly :

```
$variant['input']['id'] = "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/31576237899799";
$variant['input']['price'] = 1;

 $productVariant = $api->graph('
    mutation productVariantUpdate($input: ProductVariantInput!) 
        {productVariantUpdate(input: $input) {userErrors { field message }}}
    ',$variant);
```

Now I want to pass many product variants to mutation.

I found this GraphQL query :

```
mutation{
  ProductVariant1: productVariantUpdate(input: {
    id: "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/27868413755001",
    price: 34.97
  }){
    productVariant{ id, price }
  }

  ProductVariant2: productVariantUpdate(input: {
    id: "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/27868413788000",
    price: 34.97
  }){
    productVariant{ id, price }
  }
}
```

So it should be possible to set variables to query like 
`ProductVariant1:` and pass arrays.

How could I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a soloution. Maybe it helps anyone.

```
$variants[0]['id'] = "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/1";
        $variants[0]['price'] = 1;

        $variants[1]['id'] = "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/2";
        $variants[1]['price'] = 2;

        //build query
        $query = '';

        $countRun = 1;

        foreach($variants as $variant)
        {

            if($countRun == 1)
            {
                $query = 'mutation{
                    ProductVariant'.$countRun.': productVariantUpdate(input: {
                      id: "'.$variant['id'].'",
                      price: '.$variant['price'].'
                    }){
                      productVariant{ id, price }
                    }

                    ';
            }
            else{
                $query = $query.'ProductVariant'.$countRun.': productVariantUpdate(input: {
                    id: "'.$variant['id'].'",
                    price: '.$variant['price'].'
                  }){
                    productVariant{ id, price }
                  }

                  ';
            }

                $countRun++;
        }

        $query = $query.'}';

        $runQuery = $api->graph($query);

       return $runQuery;
```